# How can I solve this hard system of equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, radicals

Solve the system below

> \begin{align}
> &\sqrt {3x} \left( 1+\frac {1}{x+y}  \right) =2\\
> &\sqrt {7y} \left( 1-\frac{1}{x+y}  \right) =4\sqrt{2}
> \end{align}

Frankly I am disappointed, because I spent around 2 hours in solving this equation, but, finally I didn't do it so, I hope you can help me in approaching this problem.

Answer (score 5):

Square both equations. Then let $u=\frac{1}{x+y}$. Note then $x+y=\frac{1}{u}$

$$3x(1+\frac{1}{x+y})^2=4$$

$$7y(1-\frac{1}{x+y})^2=32$$

So.

$$x(1+u)^2=\frac{4}{3}$$

$$y(1-u)^2=\frac{32}{7}$$

And for $u \neq 1$

$$x=\frac{4}{3}(1+u)^{-2}$$

$$y=\frac{32}{7}(1-u)^{-2}$$

Adding both equations we have:

$$\frac{1}{u}=\frac{4}{3(1+u)^2}+\frac{32}{7(1-u)^2}$$

$$\frac{1}{u}=\frac{28(1-u)^2+96(1+u)^2}{21(1-u)^2(1+u)^2}$$

Cross multiplication, and moving terms to one side yields:

$$28u(1-u)^2+96u(1+u)^2-21(1-u)^2(1+u)^2=0$$

$$-21u^4+124u^3+178u^2+124u-21=0$$

This factors:

$$-(3-22u+3u^2)(7+10u+7u^2)=0$$

So:

$$u=\frac{11 \pm 4\sqrt{7}}{3}$$

$$x+y=\frac{3}{11 \pm 4\sqrt{7}}$$

Back substitution yields:

$$\sqrt{3x}(\frac{14 \pm 4\sqrt{7}}{3})=2$$

$$x=\frac{12}{(14 \pm 4\sqrt{7})^2}$$

$$y=\frac{3}{11 \pm 4\sqrt{7}}-\frac{12}{(14 \pm 4\sqrt{7})^2}$$

We introduced an extraneous solution when squaring so checking the possible solutions, the final solution is:

$$x=\frac{12}{(14-4\sqrt{7})^2}$$

$$y=\frac{3}{11-4\sqrt{7}}-\frac{12}{(14- 4\sqrt{7})^2}$$

If you wish, from the second equation, you can express $y$ as:

$$y=\frac{288}{7(4\sqrt{7}-8)^2}$$

In fact through the method of multiplying by conjugates we may get:

$$x=\frac{1}{21}(11+4\sqrt{7})$$

$$y=\frac{2}{7}(11+4\sqrt{7})$$

Comment: of course I can , thank you a lot

Comment: You're very welcome.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 32 instead of 8 on the RHS, line 2?

Comment: actually , after trying . also , I can't

Comment: can you put your full sol please

Comment: Yes I will it's kind of hard.

Comment: are you sure this sol satisfy the system

Comment: I plug it in calculator . I think you need to review your sol

Comment: There, I finally fixed it. I missed a square.

Answer (score 2):

Squaring 1st equation you have $3x(x+y+1)^2=4(x+y)^2$, squaring second you have $7y(x+y-1)^2=32(x+y)^2$. Put $s=x+y,y=s-x$ and we get $3s^2x+6sx+3x-4s^2=0,7s^3-7s^2x+14sx-46s^2+7s=0$. The first of these gives $x=\frac{4s^2}{3s^2+6s+3}$.

Substituting in the second we get $$s(21s^4-124s^3-178s^2-124s+21)=0$$ or $$s(3s^2-22s+3)(7s^2+10s+7)=0$$ It is clear from the original equations that $s\ne0$ and $7s^2+10s+7=0$ has no real solutions, so we have $s=\frac{1}{3}(11\pm4\sqrt7)$.

Using the equation for $x$ we get $x=\frac{1}{21}(11+4\sqrt7),y=\frac{2}{7}(11+4\sqrt7)$ or $x=\frac{1}{21}(11-4\sqrt7),y=\frac{22}{7}(11-\frac{8}{\sqrt7})$. But checking with the original equations the second solution fails (because $s-1$ is negative).

Comment: How did you factor it? Is there some method to factoring something of this sort.

Comment: If it factors into two polynomials with integer coefficients, then obviously the product of the two constant terms has to equal the constant term, and the product of the two leading terms has to equal the leading term. So you work through the possibilities. You start with a skeleton $(3s^2+hx\pm7)(7s^2+ks\pm3)$ and see whether it works. Then move to another one if it fails. With practice the process is fairly quick. Of course it may split as a linear factor. But for that it is often quicker to try the factors of the constant term directly eg is +1 a root etc.

Comment: I there is something wrong

Comment: It may originally look different from my previous answer, but through conjugates I can confirm its the same.@user348056

Comment: I should've used the conjugate when I got $x+y$ would have simplified calculations very much @user348056.